# Liferay acess document library's resource remotly

Tags: liferay, remote-access

I'm looking for accessing a resource in my document library remotly (via an Android app)
The resource is accessible for users with a given role.
So my question is how to access this resource remotly ?
I tried to pass credentials in my JSON call and implement a AutoLogin class but I can't create session remotly...

What's the right way to do this ?!
Thanks a lot !

EDIT: I'm on Liferay 6.1 CE GA3

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this site [click here](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-android-apps-that-use-liferay) , it has steps to how to create a session with liferay server and how to access data

Comment: Thanks Saleem, I edit my previous post, I omit to say that I'm on a Liferay 6.1 GA3's version and everything concerning Mobile SDK works with Liferay 6.2 and migration is not feasible in the near...

Comment: @ArnaudCharpentier you might still check that documentation as the API hasn't changed dramatically. In principle, the methods documented there should work. Fix compiler errors for renamed / new / unavailable methods of course.

Comment: you can check the source of the liferay mobile sdk and create ur own classes and API's. It's very easy as liferay mobile sdk is using the liferay's built in feature like JSON Web services. What u can do is create your own.